# Aggregate Data for Words in a String

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'd like to aggregate data based on specific words in a string.

For example, the data may look like:

```
Term        Leads
Car Trade   3
Buy Car     5
Trade Van   4
```

I would then like to break those strings down into individual words and aggregate the data. So, for the above, it would look like:

```
Word    Leads
Car     8
Trade   7
Buy     5
Van     4
```

What's the best way to do this? I've thought about using `QUERY`, but I don't know how to aggregate it for each individual word, instead of the whole string.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IF(B2:B<>"", 
 "♦"&IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, " "))&"♠"&B2:B, )), "♦")), "♠"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1'Word',sum(Col2)'Leads'"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi, I have 170,000 rows, and this formula doesn't work for that

Comment: in that case use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:B<>"", 
 "♦"&IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, " "))&"♠"&B2:B, )),, 999^99)),, 999^99), "♦")), "♠"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1'Word',sum(Col2)'Leads'"))`

Comment: This produces numbers (decimals) under the "Word" column: https://gyazo.com/2eeeb9cba7661b42fc3c855b1d01dd1c

Comment: works just fine - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wNsZ.png ...can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here's the layout. The data continues for 170,000 rows: https://gyazo.com/0f5536209b834c2e6b16f2235c315d70

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF((A2:A<>"")*(B2:B<>""), 
 "♦"&IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, " "))&"♠"&B2:B, )),, 999^99)),, 999^99), "♦")), "♠"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label Col1'Word', sum(Col2)'Impressions'"))`

Comment: That crashes the tab with so many cells. Would it be faster to use a google sheets script?

Comment: @Harry not 100% sure but the script won't help you coz there is the "execution time" and thats 30 seconds so the script won't complete for so many rows. one way to go would be to divide the data in two or more spreadsheets, use the above arrayformula and then sum it across the sheets.